# FormData give axios network error in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

This runs okay and request sent to the server successfully

```
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `http://192.168.1.12:8000/user/image`,
      data: {formData}
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

But this gives axios network error:

```
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `http://192.168.1.12:8000/user/image`,
      data: formData
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

I am using it the same way in my other project(react) but that works fine, here in this project(react-native) it gives axios network error if I don't enclosed the formData in {}.

Here is react frontend:

[image]

Here is react backend, as you can see I am getting the req.file and req.body does not have the formData:

[image]

Here is react-native result, formData is coming in req.body and req.file is undefined:

[image]

Comment: compare our form data for both the projects

Comment: in the react one I am sending the file, here in react-native I am sending the uri, its type, its name.

Comment: hence the difference

Comment: FormData is behaving differently in react and react-native, in react I get a file with req.file and there is nothing in the req.body but in react-native, I get the formData in req.body and req.file is undefined. I have watched several videos but they are not getting the axios network error.

Comment: The issue has been resolved now, it was either regarding the placement of the header, or was with the configuration of multer options that may causing the request to fail.

Comment: I am glad it is resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

pass the headers likewise -

```
   axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `http://192.168.1.12:8000/user/image`,
      data: formData,
      headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
    })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```

Comment: the formData is behaving like an object and not formData in my case.

Comment: the problem seems to be resolved, do we have to add the header after data? because I had added it in my request but between url and data. It was not working but now adding after data its working fine now :/